# List object must be coerced to to type "double" error. Strange object class behaviour

Tags: r

I have some code below. It works fine, except for a strange error if I do not "re-reinforce" my list objects as `data.frame`'s (see comment in code). The error occurs when I try to filter out empty list objects.

If I do not "re-reinforce" (`df.list <- lapply(df.list, as.data.frame)`) I get the error:

```
Error in LoadData(LCap.small) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

You can try out the code by inputting any vector with tickers. such as `LoadData(c('YHOO', 'GOOG', 'FALSEGOOG'))`. Note that the error happens when I filter out tickers that do not exist in the Yahoo databse.

What is the cause and how can it be resolved?

Code

```
LoadData <- function(x) {

 if(is.atomic(x) != TRUE & is.data.frame(x) != TRUE) stop('x must be either a data.frame or an atomic object')

 if(is.data.frame(x) == TRUE) x <-  as.character(x[,1])


 df.list <- lapply(x, function(x) {

   poss.error <- tryCatch(
    {
      quantmod::getSymbols(x, env = NULL, return.class = 'data.frame') # quantmod returns data.frame class object
    },
    error = function(e) {
      message(cat(x, "could not be retrieved"))
      return(e)
    })

   if(!inherits(poss.error, 'error')) {

      x <- poss.error %>% setNames(gsub(pattern = '^(.*)[.]', replacement = "", colnames(poss.error))) %>%
        mutate(Index = as.Date(rownames(poss.error))) %>%
        rename(Adj.Close = Adjusted) %>%
        select(Index, Open:Adj.Close)

      return(x)
   }
 })
 # add names
 names(df.list) <- x

 # make list to data.frame
 df.list <- lapply(df.list, as.data.frame) # bypass error (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

 # filter out empty data frames, error occurs here if previous line of code is not present
 df.list <- df.list[sapply(df.list, nrow) > 0]

 return(df.list)
}
```

Comment: Without line `df.list <- lapply(df.list, as.data.frame)` calling `LoadData(c('YHOO', 'GOOG'))` works for me.  Can you clarify your question?  I don't think I understand the problem.

Comment: Ahh sorry. That's because all the tickers given to the function truly exists. I have edited my question now.

Comment: Well, then obviously :-) the object returned is not a data frame.  You then have `NULL` objects in your list.  `nrow(NULL)` gives `NULL`.  This means that the result of `sapply` is something like `list(1,2,NULL)`, which cannot be converted by `as.double`.  I would either fix the return type of the anonymous function that is used to create `df.list` or filter using `is.null` in stead of using `nrow > 0`.

Comment: But why does it suddently work when I do df.list <- lapply(df.list, as.data.frame) before? Looking at str(returned.object) through browser() before the error shows that all list objects are data.frames, except the null ones

Comment: `as.data.frame(NULL)` is a data frame with zero rows and columns, i.e. `nrow(as.data.frame(NULL))` gives 0 (not NULL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anonymous function called in the first lapply sometimes returns `NULL` (when the ticker symbol does not exist).  Then your `df.list` has data frames and NULL objects.  Since `nrow(NULL) = NULL` your sapply then returns an object with numbers and NULLs, this does not convert to double.  Use `sapply(ldf.list, is.NULL)` in its place (or, maybe better, fix the function in the first lapply to always return a data frame).