# How to use the get() function? Making higher hierarchy object accessible as local variable

Tags: r

I have some code below. Now I would want to manipulate my initial top level `x` variable when an error occurs in the `tryCatch` statement. I read the documentation, but I can't really figure out how it's supposed to be used.

Some questions I can't get my head around.

What is the workflow for these type of issues? (Should I define a new enviroment for the `x` variable and reference that enrivoment when I want `x` in my local function?

How to use the get() function? I suppose for my task I need the get() function, coupled with the superassignment operator `<<-` or `assign`.

Something like. `x <<- x[! x %in% get(x, envir = "no idea")]` is what I need.

You can try out the code by specifying any vector with valid yahoo tickers, such as `LoadData(c('YHOO', 'GOOG'))`. The `tryCatch` statement is meant to catch any tickers that do not exist, and in that case I want to modify my initial ticker list (the `x` variable) to not include this ticker name. Thus the need for an `get()` operation.

```
LoadData <- function(x) {

 if(is.atomic(x) != TRUE & is.data.frame(x) != TRUE) stop('x must be either a data.frame or an atomic object')

 if(is.data.frame(x) == TRUE) x <-  as.character(x[,1])


 df.list <- lapply(x, function(x) {

   poss.error <- tryCatch(
    {
      quantmod::getSymbols(x, env = NULL, return.class = 'data.frame')
    },
    error = function(e) {
      message(cat(x, "could not be retrieved"))
      # Get the x variable that was passed to LoadData() and manipulate it. 
      return(e)
    })
```

}

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "manipulate" x? Can you provide a sample of a possible object you might call LoadData on? What is the return value of LoadData if getSymbols() is successful? In general I think you would be better off catching that error outside of LoadData() and manipulating x there where it is directly available.

Comment: @atiretoo I have edited my OP. The code is a shorter version from another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34462463/list-object-must-be-coerced-to-to-type-double-error-strange-object-class-beha/34462712#34462712

Answer (score 2):

In the function call `LoadData(c('YHOO', 'GOOG'))` mentioned in your question, the argument `x` is not a variable but simply a value. If the value is first stored in a variable, e.g. `v`, then the value of this variable can be altered by the function. (`v` is the "global" name outside the function, `x` is the name inside the function.)
Now consider the function call `LoadData(x=v)` or simply `LoadData(v)`. To get the variable `v` from inside the function, two things are needed:

- The environment `env` in which the variable `v` is stored,
- The *name* under which the variable `v` is stored in the environment `env`.

The environment `env` should be another argument of the function `LoadData`, perhaps with the global environment as default value:

```
 LoadData <- function(x,env=.GlobalEnv) { ... }
```

The trick to get the name of the variable passed to the argument `x` is to use the function `match.call`. `as.list(match.call())` is a named list and `as.list(match.call())$x` is the "symbol" that is passed to the argument `x`, i.e. "v" in our case. Then

```
x.name <- as.character(as.list(match.call())$x`)
```

is the desired name of the variable passed to the argument `x`.
Now you can use `env[[x.name]]` to alter the value of `v`. The value of `v` is `get(x.name,env)`, but this is the same as the value of `x`. So `get` is not really needed.

Here is a small example:

```
f <- function( x, v, env=.GlobalEnv )
{
  x.name <- as.character(as.list(match.call())$x)

  if ( !is.numeric(x) ) { stop(paste0(x.name," must be numeric")) }

  env[[x.name]] <- x-v
  return(NULL)
}
```

.

```
> x <- 5
> y <- 3
> z <- "abc"
> f(x,1)
NULL
> x
[1] 4
> f(y,2)
NULL
> y
[1] 1
> f(z,3)
Error in f(z, 3) : z must be numeric
>
```

If `f` is called from another function `g` to alter the value of a local variable `a`, the argument `env` has to be used:

```
g <- function()
{
  a <- 10
  print("global environment:")
  print(ls(.GlobalEnv))
  print("local environment:")
  print(ls(environment()))

  print("value of `a` before calling `f`:")
  print(a)

  f(a,1,environment())

  print("value of `a` after calling `f`:")
  print(a)

  return(NULL)
}
```

.

```
> g()
[1] "global environment:"
[1] "f" "g" "x" "y" "z"
[1] "local environment:"
[1] "a"
[1] "value of `a` before calling `f`:"
[1] 10
[1] "value of `a` after calling `f`:"
[1] 9
NULL
```

If the variable passed to `LoadData` is always the same variable and stored in the global environment, `LoadData` doesn't need any argument. Then you can simply use `<<-`.

Comment: I have edited my answer. It is no longer necessary to pass the variable name as a string to the function.